# python loop in array adding individual item prices

Tags: python

I have the following code mostly working. I just need it to allow the user to input "add-ins" until they enter the sentinel value to exit the loop and have it add the selections up. This is for a class assignment, but this is all I am having difficulties with. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    #start

def main():    #create a module - python function to hold main processing

    #declarations

    addinArray  = ["Whipped Cream", "Cinnamon", "Chocolate sauce", "Amaretto", "Irish whiskey"]
    priceArray = [0.89, 0.25, 0.59, 1.50, 1.75]  #this array holds the add-in prices

    loopFlag = ""  #sentinal value for looping
    cnt = 0
    COFFEECOST = 2  #constant to coffee cost

    addinName = ""
    totalCost = 0

    #input enter add-in name
    addinName = input("Enter on Keyboard Coffee Add-in (ex. Whipped Cream, Cinnamon, etc.) or Done to quit")
    while (addinName != "Done"):    #loop until addinName is Done
        while (cnt < len(addinArray)):
            if (addinName == addinArray[cnt]) :
                totalCost = priceArray[cnt] + totalCost
                print("Add-in ", addinName, " with a price of ", priceArray[cnt])
                print( "with a total add-in price so far of ", totalCost)
            cnt = cnt + 1  #increment counter for next element in array
        #end while

        addinName = input("Enter on Keyboard Coffee Add-in (ex. Whipped Cream, Cinnamon, etc.) or Done to quit")

    #end while
    totalCost = totalCost + COFFEECOST
    print("Total cost is: ", totalCost)
    main()
    #stop
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code locally and I found 2 things.

1. You need to reset the `cnt` variable to zero after the nested `while` loop, otherwise it won't get executed again since the condition `cnd>5` will be always `true`.
2. The `input()` call seems to throw an error, so instead I tested `raw_input()` and seemed to work.

   Hope this helps!

Comment: In Python 3, `input()` behaves like `raw_input()` in Python 2. The `print()` statements in the OP 's code suggest that Python 3 is being used.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I followed your suggestion to reset the     cnt variable to zero and the program/application works. Technically this did not have to be in python, I could have done it in pseudocode, but the instructor gave us something semi similar as an example.\

Answer (score 1):

I think that `cnt = 0` should reset after the first loop:

```
while (addinName != "Done"):    #loop until addinName is Done
    cnt = 0
```

Without this, after the first add-on cnt can reach `len(addinArray)` and never second while loop is going to be executed for new add-on.